# Efficiently resize batch of np.array images

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, image-resizing, scikit-image

I have a 4D np.array size (10000,32,32,3) that represents a set of 10000 RGB images.

How can I use `skimage.transform.resize` or other function to resize all images efficiently so that the (32,32) is interpolated to (224,224)? I'd prefer to do this with skimage, but I'm open to any solutions that don't use `tf.image.resize_images`.

My current solution is using `tf.image.resize_images`, but it's causing GPU memory issues later down in my pipeline (won't free up memory after finishing in jupyter notebook) so I'd like to replace it.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.image.resize_images(X,[224, 224])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    X = X.eval()
```

Answer (score 6):

I won't likely accept my own answer, but it seems that a simple for loop is actually fairly fast (says ~300% cpu utilization from `top`).

```
from skimage.transform import resize

imgs_in = np.random.rand(100, 32, 32, 3)
imgs_out = np.zeros((100,224,224,3))

for n,i in enumerate(imgs_in):
    imgs_out[n,:,:,:] = resize(imgs_in[n,:,:,:], imgs_out.shape[1:], anti_aliasing=True)

print(imgs_out.shape)
```

Seems to be 7-8x faster than `ndi.zoom` on my machine. Trying to parallelize this further with `multiprocessing` would be even better I think.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom) which can work with your collection of images and use spline interpolation of a given order to upsample your images:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndi

imgs_in = np.random.rand(100, 32, 32, 3)
factor = 224/imgs_in.shape[1]
imgs_out = ndi.zoom(imgs_in, (1, factor, factor, 1), order=2)
print(imgs_out.shape)
```

The resulting shape is `(100, 224, 224, 3)` as expected.

You'll have to check whether the runtime and result is acceptable for your needs. Twiddling with the order of interpolation will probably affect this: there is a noticeable speed difference between second-order and (the default) third-order splines, at the cost of interpolation quality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to work, and I might have to use it. The runtime seems to be an order of magnitude slower than the tensorflow version, but that is causing other issues.

Comment: @Austin indeed, looking at the CPU and memory use I suspect there's little vectorization going on. But I guess a pedestrian plan C might always come in handy...

Comment: Wouldn't this be a good candidate for `joblib` or multi-threading/multi-processing with 10,000 images?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I guess so. But this might apply to the question in general. Do GPUs play nicely with other kinds of parallelization? I can't say I'm particularly savvy in the subject.