# How scale down an image in a np.array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an input np.array. In each cell there is a DICOM image of 512x512 pixel. My objective is to scale down all images to 128x128 pixel, because then my input must be an np.array for the model that was constructed with shape (None, 128, 128, 1).
My input data are called train_patient and train_mask. Here some details:

```
train_patient[0].shape
```

(512, 512)

```
train_patient.shape
```

(129, 512, 512)

```
train_patient.size
```

33816576

```
train_patient[0].size
```

262144

I tried with

```
sample_width = 128
sample_height = 128
train_patient = np.resize(train_patient, (129, sample_width, sample_height, 1))
```

but when i plot it, the images are completely different from the originals.

Another option that i tried is

```
train_patient = cv2.resize(train_patient, dsize=(128, 128), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

and when i plot it, the images are disproportionate to the originals, but in practice they represent the same content. How make a proportional image? However this type of train_patient data is not appropriate to reshape as input data for the built model.
I don't know what I do because I am a beginner, so please help me! Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my suggestion is using `skimage` since it's works on `ndarrays` your usage should be very straight forward.

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rescale

You want to rescale your image by `4` which in this case means you would want to use `1 / 4 = 0.25` scaling.

```
from skimage.transform import rescale

image_rescaled = rescale(image, 0.25)
```

Comment: I put into practice the suggestion given but in this way the length, that is the number of images of the numpy.array, also decreases by 0.25

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074607/efficiently-resize-batch-of-np-array-images

Comment: you can use either `rescale` or `resize` for this

Comment: Thank you very much, with **resize** I solved the problem!

Comment: No problem glad i could help :) i would really appreciate if you could mark this one solved :)